# Rspec - GET show with respond_to on specific json view

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use Rspec-rails on my application but I fail when I try to verify the response of my request.

This is my code :

```ruby
# app/controllers/user_controller.rb

# GET api/users/:id
def show
  @user = User.find(:id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render template: "/api/users/detailed"}
  end
end
```

...

```
# spec/controllers/api/users_controller_spec.rb

require "spec_helper"

describe Api::UsersController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  describe "GET #show" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    it "assigns the requested user to @user" do
      get :show, :format => 'json', :id => user.id
      assigns(:user).should eq(@user)
    end

    it "renders the #detailed  view" do
      get :show, :format => 'json', :id => user.id
      response.should be_respond_to("api/users/detailed")
      #expect(response).to render_template("api/users/detailed")

      #expect(subject).to render_template("/api/users/detailed")
      #render(:template => "/api/users/detailed.json.rabl", :format => "json")
      #response.should render_template("/api/users/detailed.json.rabl")
    end
  end
```

I commented a part of what I have tested.
I just want to be sure that my controller `respond_to` a template called `"api/users/detailed"`.

Most often, I have the following error :

```
expecting <"api/users/detailed"> but rendering with <"">
```

I'm pretty sure my request called the controller because the first describe `"assigns the requested user to @user"` works.